# Is there a way to call a class method from another method?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and I'm working on a school homework and I would like to create a number of books, put them in the list and then print the list out in another function using a method from my class.

THIS IS MY CLASS OBJECT

```
class Knjiga
{
    public string Naslov;
    public string Avtor;
    public int StStrani;
    public int LetoIzdaje;
    public bool NaVoljo;


    public Knjiga(string aNaslov, string aAvtor, int aStStrani, int aLetoIzdaje, bool aNavoljo)
    {
        Naslov = aNaslov;
        Avtor = aAvtor;
        StStrani = aStStrani;
        LetoIzdaje = aLetoIzdaje;
        NaVoljo = aNavoljo;
    }
    public void Izpisi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Naslov + ", " + Avtor + ", " + LetoIzdaje);

    }
```

THIS IS IN MY MAIN

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Knjiga knjiga1 = new Knjiga("East of Eden", "John Steinbeck", 601, 1952, true);
        Knjiga knjiga2 = new Knjiga("From here to eternity", "James Jones", 861, 1951, true);
        Knjiga knjiga3 = new Knjiga("The Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 1200, 1954, true);

        List<Knjiga> knjigaList = new List<Knjiga>
        {
            knjiga1, knjiga2, knjiga3
        };


        foreach (var i in knjigaList)
           i.Izpisi();    //THIS ONE WORKS

        Test(knjigaList);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

THIS IS MY OTHER TEST FUNCTION

```
static void Test<T>(List<T> test)
        {
            foreach (var i in test)
                i.Izpisi(); // THIS ONE CAN'T ACCESS THE METHOD
```

When I use foreach in main() the method works, but if I try to pass the list outside the main method, I can't call the class method anymore. I'm getting "T" does not contain a definition for "Izpisi" and no accessible extension method "Izpisi" accepting a first argument of type "T" could be found. What could be done here?

Comment: Create a public function that returns the list.

Comment: It's hard to see why it's generic when you explicitly call out a function of a specific class. Why is `Test` generic and/or what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: Is it an option to define your method as `static void Test(List<Knjiga> test) {...}` or does it have to be generic? If so, why does it have to be generic and how does the generic type relates to your `Knjiga` class?

Comment: `static void Test(List<Knjiga> test)` did the trick. It's exactly what I wanted. I was trying different methods and my `static void Test<T>(List<T> test)` was the only one not showing any errors (apart from not being able to call class method) so I thought it was the right one, and I'm just doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to make this compile but you might want to take a second look at why you're doing it this way.

You could, as said in a comment, specify a list of `Knjiga`s:

```
static void Test(List<Knjiga> test)
{
    foreach (var i in test)
        i.Izpisi();
}
```

You could also condition `T` to be a `Knjiga`:

```
static void Test<T>(List<T> test) where T : Knjiga
{
    foreach (var i in test)
        i.Izpisi();
}
```

But again, the second doesn't really make sense as there's just one `Kjniga`. Do you need an `interface`; is there an inheritance structure?

Comment: I'm a total beginner and just started to take classes. We have to do a simple project before taking exam and what I'm trying to do is a simple application that would allow user to see a list of books available to rent and authors, number of pages etc. then exit back to main menu. But I want to make sure they can co back in if wanted and not just exiting program. That's why I wanted a function I could call to show the list. Changing "static void Test<T>(List<T> test)" to "static void Test(List<Knjiga> test)" did the trick